# Как производить отладку JS кода внутри Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, отладка

У меня в NodeJS программе есть такой код:

```
async function checkSelector(page, selector) {
const result = await page.evaluate(selector => {
    let el = document.querySelector(selector)
    return el ? true : false
}, selector)
return result
```

}

Т.е. я выполняю некий JS код на странице браузера.
Естественно, при отладке отладчик перепрыгивает это место сразу на строку "return result"
А я бы хотел узнать, находит ли Хром селектор на странице.

Вопрос: как настроить отладку таких участков кода в Visual Studio Code?
И где принято отлаживать такие участки кода: с браузере или в VS Code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вам поможет расширение DevTools for:

- [Chrome/NodeJS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug) (расширение от Microsoft)
- [Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codemooseus.vscode-devtools-for-chrome)
- [Edge](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools)
- [Firefox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!